# Basic Encryption Decryption

Tags: encryption

(using c#)Find this code on internet could someone please tell me how it works?

```
private void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{

    try
    {
        string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here
        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

        string cryptFile = outputFile;
        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
            RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

        int data;
        while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
            cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


        fsIn.Close();
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Encryption failed!", "Error");
    }
}
///<summary>
/// Steve Lydford - 12/05/2008.
///
/// Decrypts a file using Rijndael algorithm.
///</summary>
///<param name="inputFile"></param>
///<param name="outputFile"></param>
private void DecryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{

    {
        string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here

        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
            RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
            CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

        int data;
        while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
            fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

        fsOut.Close();
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code uses CBC with a 8 character non-randomized password as "key" where each every byte (and every leftmost bit, and then some) is likely to be zero, leaving you with a key size of less than 56 bits, easily low enough to brute force.

Furthermore it reuses the key as IV making sure that you can distinguish same passwords and/or same plaintext blocks.

In other words, this code was not generated by an expert and should not be used.

---

You need to learn cryptography before you can program a cryptographic application. Furthermore, you need to be able to determine one way or another if a third party application is secure.

If you just grab random crypto code froim the internet, the chances are almost 100% that there is some vulnerability or other. Note that security is not about the ability to run applications and make the output look random. The protocols, algorithms, applications and *system* need to be proven to be secure.

Comment: How can i make it stronger? and how i use it where i put it in a aplication?

Comment: @Pedro It doesn't particularly need to be made stronger, it needs to be thrown away.  Don't use it, and don't put it in your application.

Comment: ok thx for the advise @Xander

Comment: _trap_ -> _crap_?